# MS Access 2010 Date range results not as desired

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I am using this command to open a report

```
                            DoCmd.OpenReport "fullreport_rpt", acViewReport, , _
                            "[Assignment] ='" & lngMyEmpID & "' AND [Start] BETWEEN DateValue(#" & Me.DateRange1_txt & "#) AND DateValue(#" & Me.DateRange2_txt & "#)", _
                            acDialog, OpenArgs:=Me.reporting_combo & " For " & Me.rMonthly_txt & Me.DateRange1_txt & "-" & Me.DateRange2_txt
```

[Start] is DateValue([StartTime]) and StartTime is a DateTime field.

I want to generate a report from 01/05/2015 to 20/05/2015 but the report generated includes rows from April 2015;

image link is http://s29.postimg.org/i066yqbl3/scrshot.png

Not sure whats wrong with it.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two ways. First is to convert the date value to Double as that is how JET interprets dates.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "fullreport_rpt", acViewReport, , _
                "[Assignment] = '" & lngMyEmpID & "' AND [Start] BETWEEN " & CDbl(Me.DateRange1_txt) & " AND " & CDbl(Me.DateRange2_txt) & _
                , acDialog, OpenArgs:=Me.reporting_combo & " For " & Me.rMonthly_txt & Me.DateRange1_txt & "-" & Me.DateRange2_txt
```

Using **CDbl** is a very valid operation on Dates that come from a Date Control. If anything else, you need to use the right **formatting**, Access has a problem with [International Date Formats](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html), so try this.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "fullreport_rpt", acViewReport, , _
                "[Assignment] = '" & lngMyEmpID & "' AND [Start] BETWEEN " & Format(Me.DateRange1_txt, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " AND " & Format(Me.DateRange2_txt, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & _
                , acDialog, OpenArgs:=Me.reporting_combo & " For " & Me.rMonthly_txt & Me.DateRange1_txt & "-" & Me.DateRange2_txt
```

Comment: Access has no problems with "international" dates, you just need to do it right. DateValue does this.

Comment: @Gustav, Really? Wow !! Only wish it was the case. DateValue - uses your system settings, does not guarantee the data retrieval. Please go through the link on Allen Browne's take on this (provided with my answer). For me `DateValue("1-5-2015")` returns `01/05/2015`. In UK it is read as `1st of May 2015`, In US it is read as `5th of Jan 2015`

Comment: Yes, but that's the point you miss. DateValue is designed to work this way. DateValue will as the first attempt read the string according to your local format. Thus, DateValue will not return "01/05/2015", it will return the date value from the string "1-5-2015" which in the US happens to be 2015-01-05 while most other places, including the UK and here, it will be 2015-05-01 because it is parsed as dd-mm-yyyy. If you don't know the locale, the only safe way to represent a date by a string is to use the ISO format: yyyy-mm-dd. This will never fail and must be used in ADO where mm/dd/yyyy fails.

Comment: ISO format never fails, I agree. However, Dates need to be governed by the Date Literal (`#`), which is what makes the date to flip about if the month and date parts of the date "string" is less than 13. So, your answer `BETWEEN DateValue(" & Me.DateRange1_txt & ") AND DateValue(" & Me.DateRange2_txt & ")"` will thrown **Data Type Mismatch**. Rearranging, `BETWEEN " & DateValue(Me.DateRange1_txt) & " AND " & DateValue(Me.DateRange2_txt)` will not return the data you want to see. This is my argument.

Comment: PaulFrancis I really appreciate your help and it was a great learning curve for me.

Comment: Paul, you are very confused. "BETWEEN DateValue(" & Me.DateRange1_txt & ") AND DateValue(" & Me.DateRange2_txt & ")" will not fail if Me.DateRange2_txt contains a valid expression (and it will if a date format has been applied) , while "BETWEEN " & DateValue(Me.DateRange1_txt) & " AND " & DateValue(Me.DateRange2_txt) will fail with non-US settings becaue DateValue(Me.DateRange1_txt) will be casted to a string using the local settings prior to the concatenating with the other SQL.

Comment: @aamir, glad to be of help. Good luck =)

Comment: Paul, could you please edit your answer to leave out the first attempt using CDbl as this will fail. The other, using Format, is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateValue correctly:

```
BETWEEN DateValue(" & Me.DateRange1_txt & ") AND DateValue(" & Me.DateRange2_txt & ")", _
```

DateValue("1-5-2015") returns 2015-05-01 while

DateValue(#1-5-2015#) using your settings returns 2015-01-05 which will include dates of April.